# How to disable system and compressed memory?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, freeze, compression, memory-management

I have an hp laptop:

- core i7-6700hq
- 12gb ram
- preinstalled windows 10

Sometimes my screen freezes.

I think that's because of "system and compressed memory" because as soon as it unfreezes I check task manager an see somewhere between 1.5 and 2.5 gb ram (yes it has been over 2gb) usage
and "system and compressed memory" uses the most of the hdd connection (more than 50mb/s) and thereby saturating the disk connection I don't plan on changing my computer usage so I want to change my computer so it won't freeze my screen for 5-30 seconds.

Yes, I know "system and compressed memory" is a "feature", but it is a BROKEN FEATURE, I much prefer win7's management over win10's memory compression.

Can anyone help me disable it? I really don't want to have to buy windows 7 to fix this.

Comment: It appears your computer cannot handle it's workload. Upgrade it.

Comment: Seems to be the epitome of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: foe million other it works fine, so it is an issue with your box. Press CAPS LOCK key during the free and look if the light on the keyboard toogles or not.

Comment: I7-6700hq aka quadcore i7, 8 threads
12gb ram... 

yes i use a lot of ram, but that should be possible, my first hp laptop had no problem with it (first laptop: i5-450m dualcore 4 threads, 4gb ram)

Comment: yes for millions it works just fine... but millions of people don't hibernate instead of shutting down, millions of people don't even know about dual booting, millions of people never even thought about replacing a broken laptop screen... does that make it ok to just stop supporting hibernate, multibooting or the 40 pin lvds standard?

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the out of hand dismissal, i was close to the actual problem, someone (besides me) might have figured out that my problem wasn't ram compression, it was the 18gb of virtual ram, thanks for telling people they can just ignore my question

Comment: @DanielB my computer can handel the workload that is google chrome (yes only chrome), the problem was the 18gb of virtual ram on my HDD... ps i7 HQ (laptop) 6700 (2015 high end) no "upgrade it" doesn't help

Comment: @magicandre1981 looking back my replies were quite harsh, i'm sorry that was uncalled for (the freezes and the preceding pibkac comments got to me)
i had forgotten about my question on this forum and it's comments which is why i haven't checked (or i've forgotten the results), but i have found my answer, sorry i didn't realize you were trying to be helpful (though i think if you'd excluded the "millions" part i probably wouldn't have reacted like that)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer: it wasn't memory compression, though it was something to do with ram: windows was using my hdd (yes those ultra slow spinning disks) as extra RAM (18432mb extra ram)

to disable it go to

- control panel
- system and security
- system
- advanced system settings
- (on the advanced tab under performance) click settings...
- (on the advanced tab under virtual memory) click change...
- disable automatically manage paging file size for all drives

and either

- custom size800mb (for recording any future system errors)

or

- no paging file  (if you disable paging file or set the initial size to less than 800mb and a system error occurs, windows might not record details that could help identify the problem. do you want to continue?)

don't forget to save